# Small snippet For Finding Text File Size

Tags: c, size, notepad

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
FILE *fp;
char s[80];
int len=0;


fp=fopen("pink.txt","r");


while(fgets(s,79,fp)!=NULL)

len=len+strlen(s);   /* length of each string */
       /* spaces and newlines are also counted */

fclose(fp);

printf("length of file = %d",len);

    return 0;
}
```

i worked on this snippet it counts the string and add them into a variable len,
which is eventually used as size of the text, as characters occupy one byte,
but when i click on the properties of the notepad it gives me totally wrong answer. 15 bytes vs 18 bytes on notepad, also if i remove every new line and spaces both my code and notepad gives accurate answer, so i know its because of new line, can some one explain what is wrong.

here is what inside the text file.

```
qwe
ert
asd
zxc
```

Comment: I THINK you might be counting your line breaks. You can read a file, looking for line breaks do your properties might be considering that.

Comment: If you're running this on Windows, the line endings in the file will be two characters: carriage return plus line feed. But `fgets` will only see the line feed. So what you're seeing makes sense if there's nothing after the `c` on the last line, and you're running on Windows.

Comment: You're missing the curly brackets for delimiting the `while` body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how newline is encoded in your file. Depending on your system, new line can be encoded on two characters in your strings:

- Carriage Return (\r or CR)
- Line Feed (\n or LF)
- **Both** Carriage Return + Line feed (\r\n or CRLF)

Check the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline.) for more details

Comment: That means strlen function did not count carriage return right?

Comment: @kanishktanwar: `strlen` counts all characters (including special characters like `\n`, `\r` ...) until the NUL character (`'\0'` or simply `0`) is reached.